# Linking to external page and append its HTML within the original page's wrapper automatically

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="site-wrapper">
    //Here I want to keep appending the information without having to include
    //header and footer files in every external page
</div>

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Here's where you first land when entering the site:

```
<div data-role="main">
    <div class="center-wrapper" id="landing-container">
        <h2>Välkommen</h2>
        <p><b>Befintlig användare?</b></p>
        <a href="login.php" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Logga in</a>
        <p><b>Ny användare?</b></p>
        <a href="../includes/pages/register.php" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Registrera dig</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now if I click on "registrera dig" (register) I want to grab the contents of the file and append it to the `#site-wrapper div` above. As it works now it grabs the contents and loads a new page without the header and footer files being included since I don't have them as includes in the file. From my understanding I thought that Jquery Mobile would do this automatically but it doesn't, do I have to manually make an ajax call with Jquery and then append the content to the div or is there a way to make this happen automatically using already built-in Jquery Mobile functions? Haven't been able to find an answer from my searches so hopefully I can get one here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need AJAX to achieve this.

```
$( "#site-wrapper" ).load( "folder/page.html", function() {
 // Callback function
});
```

This snipped would solve your problem. Replace the url with your file!

Comment: Alright, thought I'd not have to do that but I guess not. Thanks.